# How to display text in span continuous with parent text

Tags: html, css

I am having a div tag which has a text then a span tag. The problem is that the span text is shown in the next line. But i want to show the span text next to the parent text. Following is the structure.

```
<div>
some text
<span>Lorem IpsumNepal is located in the southern part of the Asian continent. Nepal is a landlocked country situated between two large countries Below we have a list of all messages. Each is one row. </span>
</div>
```

So, I need some CSS to do this.

Comment: you want the `span` to be inline with "some text"?

Comment: Spans are displayed inline by default which means there's some CSS overriding that functionality that you haven't included here. See http://jsfiddle.net/6jwpx4j1/

Comment: there is no CSS. I need it.

Comment: Strage behaviour. `span` is an inline element and should be displayed in line with the text. There must be other CSS-rules in place.

Comment: span is inline element, so what you expect is the default behavior. Check you might already be having some css making them in 2 different lines.

Comment: @Mouser yes, u r right. but when the text is more then it goes to new line.

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir it does that already, somemthing else must be effecting it: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/99fv6cx6/)

Comment: Use `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @jmore009 yes, i checked there was other css which was floating it left. now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your css

```
span{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As others have said, this is the default behavior of a span. Your likely to have some css that is overriding this default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want the span to appear below the parent text try using the following css style

```
span {
display: block;
}
```

Results:
some text
Lorem IpsumNepal is located in the southern part of the Asian continent. Nepal is a landlocked country situated between two large countries Below we have a list of all messages. Each is one row.